# Migrating volatile data from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, business-intelligence

I work for a growing company. The company has lived off of spreadsheets for a long time and is now starting to feel the growing pains. We absolutely need to move from spreadsheets to a relational database. The problem is, there's a ton of spreadsheets (very similar but not always exact) and they're constantly being updated with order status and other things.

Every project has anywhere from 1 to 10 spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet contains the list of materials for one part of the project. Every time a shipment of parts arrives or is delayed, each affected spreadsheet needs to be updated, which can be a lot of spreadsheets.

Right now I'm looking at roughly 1200 spreadsheets. They are being touched frequently throughout the day to reflect updates. They are all from a template, but there are always write-ins and other notes that would completely screw up an automatic import.

We're a 7-day-per-week operation, so doing this over a weekend doesn't help. I can't get much time from the responsible department because they're so overburdened with having to manually update hundreds of spreadsheets per day.

How can I safely import or **facilitate human importing** of all of this data into a database table? Are there tools out there that can help? I don't want to let a script do this without supervision since it could result in huge problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Create your database, determine your table structures and you can probably use an ETL tool such as SSIS to transfer your data.

Comment: Can I have it show the original excel next to the imported data for human verification?

Comment: A database is just a database - typically you're using some other tool on top of it to view/modify the data.  You could query the inserted data back out for comparison purposes.